# ansible: Conditional not working

Tags: ansible

In the following tasks, I am trying to run the second one conditionally but the inequality operator does not seem to work:

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ rv_server_response.stdout }}"

- name: setup_ssl -> Install certificate using certbot
  command: some_conditional_command
  when: rv_server_response.stdout != 200
```

The second task always gets executed.

```
TASK [provision_rancher_server : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server] => {
    "msg": "200"
}

TASK [provision_rancher_server : setup_ssl -> Install certificate using certbot] *******************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [server]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registered variable is the status code returned from the `uri` module of `ansible`.

It turns out it is treating it as string, therefore quoting it solves the problem:

```
when: rv_server_response.stdout != "200"
```